# How can I map entity using a Jooq?

Tags: java, jooq

I have a trouble: can't figure out how to map result of Jooq query.

I have 2 entities: Payment method and Currency for it. Payment method contains a List inside. Both are stored in different tables.

I get one:

```
public Optional<PaymentMethod> getMethod(Long id) {
return this.dslContext.selectFrom(PAYMENT_METHOD)
    .where(
        PAYMENT_METHOD.ID.eq(id),
        PAYMENT_METHOD.DELETED.eq(false)
    ).fetchOptional().map(v -> methodDao.mapper().map(v));
```

And want to get currencies too, by using a:

```
return this.dslContext.select(asterisk())
    .from(PAYMENT_METHOD)
    .join(PAYMENT_METHOD_CURRENCY)
    .on(PAYMENT_METHOD_CURRENCY.METHOD_ID.eq(id))
    .where(
        PAYMENT_METHOD.ID.eq(id),
        PAYMENT_METHOD.DELETED.eq(false)
    )
    .fetch()
    .map(...)...
```

So, how can I map this further?

I have a decision for a single entity inside other, like that:

```
private PaymentProviderMethod mapMethod(Record record) {
final PaymentMethodRecord methodRecord = record.into(PAYMENT_METHOD);
final PaymentProviderRecord providerRecord = record.into(PAYMENT_PROVIDER);
return new PaymentProviderMethod(
    methodDao.mapper().map(methodRecord),
    providerDao.mapper().map(providerRecord));
```

But have no idea how to map list in this case. Could u help, please?

Comment: Can you show the exact target data structure (`class` definition and relevant properties)?

Comment: Sure:) All, except last field, placed in PAYMENT_METHOD table

Long id;
Long providerId;
String name;
JSONB translations;
Long type;
LocalDateTime createdAt;
LocalDateTime updatedAt;
Boolean deleted;
Boolean enabled;
Double fee;
Long[] countryIds;
Boolean online;
JSONB params;
Long groupId;
Boolean enabledForTest;
String reasonForDisabled;
Long position;
List<Currency> currencies;

@Getters, setters etc

Comment: You can edit your question...

Comment: Please NEVER put more information into comments. Always [edit] your question instead. Or can you read the code you added as comment?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to nest collections in with jOOQ, then you're probably looking for the [`MULTISET`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/) or [`MULTISET_AGG`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/multiset-agg-function/) operator along with [ad-hoc conversion](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/), which allows for type safe [nesting collections directly in SQL, if your database product support SQL/XML or SQL/JSON](https://blog.jooq.org/jooq-3-15s-new-multiset-operator-will-change-how-you-think-about-sql/).

The following might not be the exact query you were looking for, but you get the idea:

```java
// Assuming the usual static import:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

ctx.select(
       PAYMENT_METHOD.ID,
       PAYMENT_METHOD.PROVIDER_ID,
       PAYMENT_METHOD.NAME,
       ...
       multiset(
           select(
               PAYMENT_METHOD_CURRENCY.ID,
               PAYMENT_METHOD_CURRENCY.NAME,
               ...
           )
           .from(PAYMENT_METHOD_CURRENCY)
           .where(PAYMENT_METHOD_CURRENCY.METHOD_ID.eq(PAYMENT_METHOD.ID))
       ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(Currency::new)))
   )
   .from(PAYMENT_METHOD)
   .fetch(Records.mapping(PaymentMethod::new))
```

The above example uses `MULTISET` for a nested, correlated subquery, but you coudl do the same thing with `MULTISET_AGG` and a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` clause, especially if your dialect doesn't support [correlating derived tables, see issue #12045](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12045). The whole query is type safe. If you change your `PaymentMethod` or `Currency` DTO classes, the query will stop compiling until you fix your projections.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Jooq version less than `13.15` then you cannot use multiset. And for me I had the same issue, and I solved it by manually mapping the records. I did that with Kotlin, but I think you can figure out the idea from there:

```
private fun mapRecords(records: Result<Record>): List<PaymentMethod> {
        val paymentMethodCurrencies = records.into(PaymentMethodCurrencyRecord::class.java)
            .map(::mapPaymentMethodCurrency)
            .groupBy { it.paymentMethodId }

        val paymentMethods = records.into(PaymentMethodRecord::class.java).distinct()
            .map { 
                mapPaymentMethod(it, paymentMethodCurrencies[it.id])
            }

        return paymentMethods
    }
```